# Change data based on selection using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following ajax call:

```
.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/showResult",
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "dateFrom": $('#txtDateFrom').val(),
                        "dateTo": $('#txtDateTo').val(),
                        "ddlType": $("#ddlType").children("option").filter(":selected").val(),
                        "ddlTer": $("#ddlTer").children("option").filter(":selected").val(),
                        "ddlFilter": $("#filter").children("option").filter(":selected").val()
                    }), // parameters
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#loader').html('<img src="Images/loading.gif" />');
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#loader').html('');
                        //To delete the whole tr except the first one.
                        $("#tblUsers").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                        $('#tblUsers').append(JSON.stringify(result));

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                    }


                });
```

That will call the following **Web method**

```
[WebMethod]
public string showResult(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo,string ddlFilter)


{
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
      string result = "";
   // return dateFrom.ToString();
 string filter=ddlFilter.ToString();
 var sp = db.divideTypes(dateFrom, dateTo,ddlFilter).ToList();
 foreach (var u in sp)
 {
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+u.depno+"</td>";
        result += "</tr>";
 }
 return result;
}
```

this will append the returned **result** to table. 
i want to add drop down list that will change the data of parameter   `"ddlFilter"`, so the result will be changed.

i notice that there's .change() call but where to place it?

Comment: You want to call `ajax function` when `filter`changes ?

Comment: Yes but in different way, i want to call the same ajax function which is `"WebService.asmx/showResult",` but with different 
`"ddlFilter": $("#filter").children("option").filter(":selected").val()` parameter
which will be changed by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your ajax call lives in a function called `myAjaxCall`

Then you can trigger the function on change of `#ddlFilter` like so:

`$('#ddlFilter').change(myAjaxCall);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` event of `dropdown` which will send the `selected value` to `webservice method`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="filter" onchange="CallService()" runat="server">

</asp:DropDownList>

function CallService(){
.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/showResult",
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "dateFrom": $('#txtDateFrom').val(),
                        "dateTo": $('#txtDateTo').val(),
                        "ddlType": $("#ddlType").val(),
                        "ddlTer": $("#ddlTer").val(),
                        "ddlFilter": $("#filter").val()
                    }), // parameters
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#loader').html('<img src="Images/loading.gif" />');
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#loader').html('');
                        //To delete the whole tr except the first one.
                        $("#tblUsers").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                        $('#tblUsers').append(JSON.stringify(result));

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                    }


                });
}
```

Also you can get value of dropdown simply by using `$("#dropdownid").val()` so no need to write

```
$("#filter").children("option").filter(":selected").val()
```

Just use

```
$("#filter").val()
```

Comment: Thank you for reply